# How can I say "I know him well" in a formal way

Tags: writing, formality

I need help in formal writing.
Can somebody tell me how to say "I know him well after 2 year teaching him" formaly?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't see anything particularly "informal" about saying you know someone well. Except that in some formal contexts it's not really appropriate to mention *personal* details like that at all.

Comment: I apologize, but this is off-topic (we do not do ghost writing here), not constructive (there can be any number of equally valid answers), and too localized (it is unlikely that other people will be researching rewordings of this exact phrase).

Answer (score 2):

Presumably you are looking for a way to give one of your students a recommendation. I would recommend something like

> I have had the privilege of teaching him for two years, during which time I have come to know him quite well.